# Accessing an iOS URL Scheme, at Runtime

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url

This is fairly straightforward.

I have an app that publishes a URL scheme, [like so](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app).

In the spirit of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I'd like to avoid referencing it, using constant strings. Instead, I'd like to fetch it from the bundle.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet prints the URL schemes defined in an app's `Info.plist`:

```
if let types = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleURLTypes"] as? [[String: Any]] {
    var result = [String]()
    for type in types {
        guard let schemes = type["CFBundleURLSchemes"] as? [String] else { continue }
        guard let scheme = schemes.first else { continue }
        result.append(scheme)
    }
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll give it a go, in a bit. This will probably get a greencheck. I know this is a very short question, but it's one that could matter a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by leveraging [Gereon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1918561/gereon) answer. Here's how I did it:

```
/* ###################################################################################################################################### */
// MARK: - Fleshing out the Addressable (General) -
/* ###################################################################################################################################### */
public extension LGV_MeetingSDK_AddressableEntity_Protocol {
    /* ################################################################## */
    /**
     This fetches the first URL scheme from the bundle, renders it as a String, and returns it.
     */
    var urlScheme: String {
        guard let bundleTypes = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleURLTypes"] as? [[String: Any]],
              let myURLScheme = (bundleTypes.first?["CFBundleURLSchemes"] as? [String])?.first
        else { return "" }

        return myURLScheme
    }
}

/* ###################################################################################################################################### */
// MARK: - Fleshing out the Addressable (User) -
/* ###################################################################################################################################### */
public extension HeartOfRecovrr_Member {
    /* ################################################################## */
    /**
     This returns an addressable URL for this member record.
     */
    var urlString: String { "\(urlScheme)://user/\(id)" }
}
```

[And here it is, in my general-purpose Swift extensions package](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox/blob/5a5e32f3ef4373e678bf639110724285b9dff8b7/Sources/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox/RVS_Generic_Swift_Toolbox_Extensions/RVS_Bundle_Extensions.swift#L57).